# Action has been passed certification test, but still cannot find it on Google Home app

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created my company's action and passed Google's certification test. The status has been transferred to "Deployed". Action can be also found on the Assistant Discovery web page. But I still cannot find it on the Home app. This has been three days. Is there any setting I missed? Or just it take such a long time for the first-time deployment?

Comment: Have you tried sending it to your device via the discovery web page?

Comment: Have you received any other communications?